# Images don't load on different versions of Mac after changing the app server(Laravel)

Tags: linux, laravel, image, exchange-server

Images don't load on different versions(example High Sierra,Mojave) of Mac after changing the app server.
This is a laravel-vue application.
This project run an ubuntu 20 server,php version 7.3.
I think the problem the safari version but I don't know how can I solve.
Thanks in advance for any help.

I tried run php artisan storage:link command but not is the problem.

Comment: Any error either in the log or the browser?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JayF no,the browser console and the log are empty also.

Comment: Just delete the linked storage folder in public folder and recreate again with `php artisan storage:link`. High chances it will work.

Comment: I tried this but not is the problem.- @Vishnu